# Is there a word for fake or incorrect historical reproductions?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

I could've sworn there was a specific word for the situation where someone in the present makes up some historical detail to appear authentic, manufactures an antique that is actually anachronistic for the period it is supposed to be from, or attempts to restore some historical artifact with incorrect details.

In a sense this word would be opposite to "retrofuturism" as it is a similar mistake made in the opposite direction of time. But more than anything I want to describe the incorrect restoration of some historical artifact, in an attempt to hide the fact that it was not original.

e.g. "The door latches, while historic looking, were actually a(n) [word] that didn't actually fit the time period of the building's construction, and we know they were installed in the 90s by someone trying to pass them off as original"

While anachronism would fit, it doesn't describe the act of the item being fraudulent, and has a more neutral connotation.

Comment: Alternate history pieces?

Comment: Yes. There's a whole genre of alternative history fantasy (or science fiction). Read [_1632_ (it's free)](https://www.baen.com/1632.html) to see how it works.

Comment: "Alternate history pieces" does come close, but I think it's maybe lacking due to alternate histories being above board in their fictitiousness. But it did lead me to "faux historical piece" which I think fits the criteria.

Comment: Admittedly I have not titled this question very well for the body that I have written, and "alternate history" does fit the bill quite nicely for a word that is the opposite of retrofuturism.

Comment: @brubsby: you can [edit](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/595077/edit) your question, including the title.

Comment: Why not "counterfeit" which is applied to something that is faked with the intent to defraud?

Comment: what is the intent of this item, is it for sale as a fraud or to fit into their victorian house but be more handy?

Comment: There is [historical negationism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_negationism) but it involves illegitimate historical revisioning or forging of historical records/documents/text. It doesn't talk about artefacts or antiques; so I couldn't be sure if it is the term you are looking for.

Comment: *Ersatz* is an adjective that can come in handy, too.

Comment: The OP has never responded to the above question by WendyG, and without that response, the question is unanswerable. The term to use will greatly depend on the motivations.

Comment: "anachronism" is ruled out by the OP, but seems the best word. The OP says it's neutral, but it's often negatively - if you say something is an anachronism in a story or film, that's usually a criticism.

Comment: It is **an inaccurate reproduction**.

Comment: You aren't thinking of *coquillard*, are you? They were notorious imposters who sold shells allegedly blessed on the St Jacques de Compostelle pilgrimage. Doing so was a crime in France. The term extended metaphorically, and was used by Conan Doyle.

Answer (score 1):

If the maker or presenter of the reproduction is actively *pretending*  that it's genuine, I'd call the reproduction a *sham*.

Sham is defined by [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sham) as "an imitation or counterfeit purporting to be genuine."

Answer (score 1):

The technical term is (historical) replica.

See Wikipedia: [**replica**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replica)

faulty, inaccurate, inexact replica

Just one example of inaccurate replica:

> The newly resurfaced painting bears similarities to inaccurate
> replicas of the original, potentially suggesting that it’s a copy of a
> copy, according to Prignitz-Poda.

[Smithsonian and Frida Kahlo painting](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/smart-news/dealer-claims-he-located-lost-frida-kahlo-masterpiece-experts-are-skeptical-180975245/)

Guns:

> If you visit the USS Constitution in Boston these days, the cannons
> you’ll see on her gun deck aren’t the originals launched with the
> ship. The guns aboard the ship are replicas, and only two of them are
> capable of firing salute charges. Even when the sailors aboard
> Constitution fire salutes, it’s a far cry from the way cannons were
> loaded and fired when Old Ironsides was first laid. [...]
>
> In fact, they’re inaccurate replicas, with 18 of them even bearing the
> Royal Cipher of King George II.

[Original guns and inaccurate replicas](https://www.wearethemighty.com/popular/uss-constitution-original-guns/)

Comment: I am in the antiques business actually and yes, this is the most useful term. Further, in the question "didn't actually fit the time period" we would say the replica was of a style not contemporary with the work. Or in "a later/earlier style." The OP seems to assume any later modification of an artifact is intentional misdirection instead of, say, repair or changing taste. Things break and people 50 years later prefer machine-pressed brushed nickel over hand-made brasses

Answer (score -1):

### History

"Historical sophistry". [Sophistry](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sophistry), the clever use of arguments that seem true but are really false, in order to deceive people

A few words can be  combined with "history" to mean "history" that has been altered. Examples would be

"Fabricated"/"engineered"/"counterfeit"/"forged"/"spurious" history.

### Antique

["Newfangled"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/newfangled) may mean recently made for the first time, but not always an improvement on what existed before. It does not however mean "forged antique piece/s". Word combinations such as these can be used to mean "forged antique piece/s"

"Imitation antiques"

"Ersatz goods" [Ersatz](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ersatz): used instead of something else, usually because the other thing is too expensive or rare:

"Faux antiques", [Faux](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/faux) not real, but made to look or seem real

Answer (score -1):

Is it be of the following?

*counterfeit
*bogus
*sham
*mock (mock-up)
*spurious
*inauthentic
*unauthentic
*imitation
*factitious
*dupe
*dummy
*forgery
*phony
*approximation
*impression
*semblance
*knockoff
*rip-off
*fabrication
*feigned
*Janus-faced

I will do a more thorough search if not but I figured I’d attempt a quick attempt to locate the word. If it’s not one of the words I’ve listed, then I have a feeling that it’s likely to be a slang word, or word that’s popular in a particular region. Let me know either way, thanks.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The above comment has been automatically generated, so it may not be very helpful in itself. You may wish to spend some time browsing this site in order to get a sense of what kind of answers are expected at it.